# How to create autosuggestion with Azure Cosmos Document DB?

Tags: sql-server, azure, full-text-search, azure-cosmosdb

I want to create autosuggestion within Azure Cosmos Db.

I can see that there is Azure cognitive search and Elastic stack services that can be used to achieve this. However, I have couple 1000 records only, and they are not expected to grow very large.

Now Cognitive search and Elastic stack feels like overkill.

So How can I create autosuggestion (index and queries) with Azure cosmos DB?

The Source of my NOSQL Cosmos DB data is SQL DB. I switched from SQL to NOSQL only for autosuggestion thing only because FullText search and LIKE on SQL side are not faster. dotnet core api is responsible for syncing of SQL to NOSQL Db Data.

Comment: For 1-2 k records you can simply implement this on client side.

Comment: @gotqn it is around 1000 for Dev environment. However, in production it is around 100K